# How to set jshint/jsxhint "esnext" option in Atom

Tags: jshint, atom-editor, jsxhint

I am using Atom's `linter`, `react`, and `linter-jshint`/`linter-jsxhint`.
In my JSX files, I keep getting the warning

> Warning: 'import' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option). (W119)

That's pretty straightforward. I did some searching, and found that this can be set under the `jshintConfig` option in `package.json` (when using NPM). My project uses NPM and I have a `package.json`. I added:

```json
"jshintConfig": {
  "esnext": true
}
```

After that, I did a reload but the warnings persist. I also modified my `linter-jshint`/`linter-jsxhint` config in Atom (`config.cson`) with:

```json
"linter-jshint":
  harmony: true
  esnext: true

"linter-jsxhint":
  harmony: true
  esnext: true
```

And did a reload but that didn't help it either.

So: when using `linter-jshint`/`linter-jsxhint` as Atom packages, how to I set the `esnext` option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First possibility, **recommended** : you can create a `.jshintrc` in you home directory and jshint will read it in case there is none in the project directory. You might need to restart Atom after.

Another possibility **not recommended** : you could also change the config of jshint in Atom and specify the location of your global `.jshintrc`if for some reason you don't want to put it in your home directory with the flag `--config`

```
'linter-jshint':
  'jshintExecutablePath': /path/to/jshint --config /path/to/.jshinrc
```

Run 'which jshint' to find the path.
It is not recommended because every other `.jshinrc` file (in the project, etc.) will be ignore:

> jshint will look for this configuration in a number of locations, stopping at the first positive match:
>
> - The location specified with the --config flag
> - A file named package.json located in the current directory or any parent of the current directory (the configuration should be declared as the jshintConfig attribute of that file's JSON value)
> - A file named .jshintrc located in the current directory or any parent of the current directory
> - A file named .jshintrc located in the current user's "home" directory (where defined)

Comment: Why is the config route not recommended?

Comment: Because every other .jshinrc file will be ignore (see edited answer).

Comment: Is it a problem if `which jshint` gives no output and `jshint` gives `-bash: jsxhint: command not found`? I only have it installed through Atom's `linter` and `linter-jshint` packages, I never put it on my system stand-alone.

Comment: If you already get warning i guess not. It can work because there is jshint in your nodes_modules: atom might look for it first in your node_modules before looking for it globally (it makes sense because that way, everybody working on this project has the same version of jshint).

Answer (score 78):

You can create a `.jshintrc` in your project folder, it will be read by the linter as a json source file.

To use esnext option,

```
{
    "esnext": true
}
```

You will probably need to reopen your JS file to be able to see the new changes.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a new file? I liked the idea of putting in the config better

Comment: Best to do it on a project by project basis rathe than setting a global options as some point in the future you might be back here asking why your jshint installation isn't falling over when it hits new ES specs.

Comment: Thank you! @peduxe

Answer (score 5):

You can use the inline configuration adding this comment in your file .js:

/* jshint esversion: 6 */

> http://jshint.com/docs/