# gulp-typescript compilation issues?

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a gulp task to compile the ts into js. Here is the code:

```
var typescript  = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([scriptsSrc])
        .pipe(typescript({
            declarationFiles: true,
            noExternalResolve: false,
            sortOutput: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
        .pipe(stripDebug())
        .pipe(uglify())     
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream : true}));
  });
```

My main.ts file:

```
class Game extends Phaser.Game {   

    constructor() {
        super(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content',null);
        this.state.add("play", new states.PlayState());
        this.state.start("play");
    }

}

var mygame = new Game();
```

play.ts:

```
module states {

    export class PlayState extends Phaser.State {
        create() {
            var text = "Hello!!!";
            var style = { font: "65px Arial", fill: "#ff0000", align: "center" };
            this.game.add.text(0, 0, text, style);
        }
    }   
}
```

I got the following compile error:

> src/scripts/main.ts: line 4, col 1, 'class' is available in ES6 (use
>   esnext option) or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).
>
> src/scripts/scenes/play.ts: line 0, col 0, 'module' is only available
>   in ES6 (use esnext option). src/scripts/scenes/play.ts: line 1, col 15, Expected 'from' and instead saw '{'. src/scripts/scenes/play.ts:
>   line 3, col 5, Expected '(string)' and instead saw 'export'.
>   src/scripts/scenes/play.ts: line 3, col 11, Missing semicolon.
>   src/scripts/scenes/play.ts: line 3, col 12, 'class' is available in
>   ES6 (use esnext option) or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).
>   src/scripts/scenes/play.ts: line 9, col 1, Unrecoverable syntax error.
>   (81% scanned).

My compiled files are able to run in Safari and Google Chrome without any problem. But how to deal with the error message? My version of tsp is 1.6.2.

Comment: The first step - set "esnext" option to true, as was told in the error text. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080498/how-to-set-jshint-jsxhint-esnext-option-in-atom

Comment: try to use namespace keyword instead of module

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `esnext` option and using namespaces as suggested in the comments, should do the trick. Can you please confirm this is working?